# How to display data from eight LINQ to SQL tables in a single view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm pretty new to MVC and I'm trying to pull data from 8 different tables (1 record from each table but several fields from each record in each table)

I read how to do this with 2 tables and joining, but when I try to join more than two tables I get errors.

Each table has an ID field in each record and that is what I need to query against.

UPDATE:

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class StoreInfoViewModel
    {
        public List<AWS_Ticket> tickets { get; set; }
        public List<AWS_TNF_StepOne> tnf { get; set; }
        public List<AWS_TNF_StepTwo> tnf2 { get; set; }
        public List<AWS_DBU> dbu { get; set; }
        public List<GetStoreInfoResult> storeInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class StoreInfoController : Controller
    {
        PortalDataContext db = new PortalDataContext();
        //
        // GET: /StoreInfo/
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var tickets = db.AWS_Tickets.Where(x => x.Store_Number == id);
            var tnf = db.AWS_TNF_StepOnes.Where(x => x.Store_Number == id);
            var tnf2 = db.AWS_TNF_StepTwos.Where(x => x.Store_Number == id);
            var dbu = db.AWS_DBUs.Where(x => x.StoreNumber == id);
            var storeInfo = db.GetStoreInfo(id);

            StoreInfoViewModel model = new StoreInfoViewModel();
            model.tickets = tickets.ToList();
            model.tnf = tnf.ToList();
            model.tnf2 = tnf2.ToList();
            model.dbu = dbu.ToList();
            model.storeInfo = storeInfo.ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
```

Here's my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Team_Portal_v3.Models.StoreInfoViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<div>
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Store Number: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].StoreNum)
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>24 Hour Store? @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].Is24Hour)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    City / State: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].City) , @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].State)
                </td>
                <td>
                    Store Phone: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].StorePhone)
                </td>
                <td>
                    DBU Installed? @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].DBUInstalled)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Owner: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].Owner)
                </td>
                <td>
                    Owner Phone: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].OwnerPhone)
                </td>
                <td>
                    Store Status: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].StoreStatus)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Division: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].Division)
                </td>
                <td>
                    Region: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].Region)
                </td>
                <td>
                    Expected Opening Date: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.storeInfo[0].OpeningDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

I am not receiving any error on init running of the app, it when I try to go to the index with and numeric ID that I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Team_Portal_v3.Models.StoreInfoViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Team_Portal_v3.Models.StoreInfoViewModel]'.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: are these tables in a dbml file then? and are they mapped together by foreign keys?  Also please include the code that you tried.

Comment: What type of data access layer are you using? Are you using ORM like Entity Framework? What are you loading the data into? What Type of Linq statement did you try?

Comment: An 8 table join seems like a *really* good candidate for a stored procedure.

Comment: What is your table/domain structure?

Comment: My tables are in a dbml file, there are no mappings to foreign keys. I using Entity Framework. I haven't try to write code for all eight tables, I got to three tables and started seeing errors so I don't have code to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory here.  You passed in a single `StoreInfoViewModel` but your view was expecting an `IEnumerable<StoreInfoViewModel>`.

Either your view needs to be updated to only expect a single `StoreInfoViewModel`

```
@model Team_Portal_v3.Models.StoreInfoViewModel
```

or you need to actually pass in a list of `StoreInfoViewModel` from your controller/action

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be unpopular but you are better off using stored procedure when you cross 3 joins. [Here is article on how to do it.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: This only worked if I my stored procedure returned one record, there are four tables that could return more than one record. So it errors out. I updated my original post with more info.